# 2 dog owners - one night owl, one early riser

Tags: dogs, sleep, hedgehog

My SO and I are adopting a 6-year-old (male) Parson Russell Terrier. We live in an apartment, and are buying one dog bed for the main living space, and one in my office (a small bedroom). In the main living, my SO typically keeps the lights on until ~2 am. I usually get up around 6:30 am and turn the lights on. Will this be an issue, if the dog doesn't have much time with the lights off?

Other details: In my office, we also have a hedgehog (in a cage). I don't know how comfortable they'll both be with the scent of the other so close by. Because of this, I'm not counting on him being able to use the bed in my office.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!